# How to figure out weekly, monthly and seasonal start and end dates in nonconsecutive data

Tags: python, algorithm, date, python-3.x, calendar

I have a series of dates stretching back in years, however, they are not consecutive, meaning that in some weeks there are 7 dates, in some other weeks there are 3 dates, and in some extreme case there is only one date for that week.

I need to identify and mark the start and the end dates for every week for which there are dates available. For example, `2015-06-23`, `2015-06-24`, `2015-06-25`, and `2015-06-27` are recorded for the week starting from `2015-06-22 (Mon)`, so `2015-06-23` and `2015-06-27` should be the start and the end of that week respectively. If there is only one date recorded for a given week, then that date should be the start and the end of that week simultaneously.

Extending the same concept to months, I need to identify and mark the start and the end dates recorded for any given month no matter how many dates there are for a given month.

Similarly, the same applies to seasons where the definition of four seasons (in terms of start and end months) may be customizable. That is, I may define the four seasons as: Spring (Mar - May), Summer (Jun - Aug), Autumn (Sep - Nov), Winter (Dec - Feb), or I may shift the months to use some different definition. In fact, we may ditch the conventional concept of season entirely, and just define four consecutive periods with three consecutive months in each. Given such a definition, I need to identify the start and the end dates available for each given period/season.

What is a time-efficient algorithm for doing all of the above?

Answer (score 1):

It is a variant of [Element Distinctness Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), where you are required to find 2 specific instances of each "distinct" element.

(Reduction from element distinctness can be done by adding `i / epsilon` time for the `i`th element, and then finding out if there is a week with more than one date).

Element distinctness is usually solved by one of two ways, which can be also applied here:

1. Sort the data, then iterate it. In sorted data it is easy to find the first and last occurance in each week/month/year/...
2. Populate a hash-map that maps from a week number (integer) to a list, including all the dates in this week. Finding the first (earliest) data is easy, and you can then define this week to be "week 1", later, it is easy to calculate the offset (in weeks) for each date from this "week 1". So, first find this "week 1" date (single iteration), then - create the desired map (in a second iteration, and each insertion is `O(1)` on average), and lastly - iterate the map and for each date - output the minimal and maximal date in the list associated to this week.

Note that if you are looking for scalable solution, the 2nd approach can be translated to [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) pretty easily.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, they are very helpful. I have one question though: for the first method (sorting), after the dates are sorted (e.g. in descending order), as you iterate through them, let's say the current date you are on is a Wed and the next date is a Tue, but how do you distinguish if that is a Tue in the same week or a Tue in the previous week? As mentioned, it is possible that some days in any given week is missing in my data.

Comment: @skyork A Tuesday after a Wednesday is always in the next week.

Comment: not necessarily if you sort the dates in descending order, i.e. from latest to oldest, like I suggested above. Again, the dates in my data are irregular so the number of days in a week is not constant. The same kind of problem still exists if you sort in the other direction, e.g. how do you know a Thursday after a Wednesday is in the current week, or the week after, without getting extra info such as the difference between two dates?